# Props only showing under inline if statement in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Been fooling around with some code and came into something tricky.  Currently I am showing user data if the user isAuthenticated.  However, I have to put this.props.user ? in the inline statement.  Otherwise, this.props.user comes back as undefined, although, with this.props.user ? it works.

Here is the code

```
// import React from "react";
// import { connect } from "react-redux";
// import { getUser } from "../store/actions/userActions";
// import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {  Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as actions from '../store/actions/auth'

class UserDetailView extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.onTryAutoSignup()
    this.props.getfetchUser(this.props.username)
    console.log(this.props)
    const user = this.props.user
  }




  render(){




    return(

      <div>

      {
        this.props.user//need this or the below become undefined && this.props.isAuthenticated ?
  <div>
    Welcome {this.props.user.username} {this.props.user.email}   
  </div> 
        :
      <div><Link to='/login/'>Login</Link></div>  

      }
      </div>
   )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {

  return{
    isAuthenticated: state.token !== null,
    user: state.user,
    username: state.username
  }
}
const mapStateToDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
    logout: () => dispatch(actions.logout()),
    onTryAutoSignup: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState()),
    getfetchUser: id => dispatch( actions.fetchUser( id ) )
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapStateToDispatch)(UserDetailView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply because on the "first load" of the component the user data is not valid (I assume, I can't see your reducers)

So let's say your reducer sets the default user as `null`

- now this component is loaded
- `componentDidMount` dispatches and calls `getfetchUser`
- `getfetchUser` will take some time...
- the component `render` is not waiting so it will call `render` method
- but `user` is not set yet as you didn't get the response from the server
- so on the first render, you see `user` as null
- but as soon as ajax call returns it sets the user and you are good

so that's why you see this "weird" behavior, but that's how it is in the current implementation.

You can try different tricks to make sure you are good, like:

- stick to what you did
- add a `loading` flag, so you could know you are waiting for a response from the server. This is the better option because you could handle errors from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a check because you are accessing the username and email attributes of the user object.

Assuming on initial render,

```
user = {} // this wont have properties initially
isAuthenticated = true
```

You try to access the email and username, which don't exist at that point of time.

To avoid this,

Maybe you can pass the isAuthenticated inside your user object itself. This will maintain integrity.